# scrollTop only works on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts, scrolltop

So I have an amcharts graph, and when I click on a bar in the graph, a div next to it scrolls to that data from the bar. My problem is when I click anytime after the first time it goes to the top or sometimes a random position. I want to be able to scroll to each piece of data when clicked.

This is my code for the scrollTo method:

```
"listeners": [{
  "event": "clickGraphItem",
  "method": function (event) {
    var buildNumber = event.item.category;
    var id = '#buildNumber' + buildNumber;
    var buildFailureObject = $('#buildNumber' + buildNumber);
    $('#infodiv').animate({ scrollTop: $(buildFailureObject).position().top - 20 }, 2000);
 }
}]
```

The info div is where the scrolling happens. To clarify, the first click works and takes me to the "buildFailureObject", but the next clicks either take me back to the top of the infodiv or sometime a random close by spot.

I have looked at questions close to mine and preventDefault has not helped me nor has return false.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: the fact that's scrolling to 'random' positions make me believe there could be something wrong with the data sent along the event. Have you `console.log()`ed the `event` and/or `event.item` objects?

Comment: Can you please post code so i can verify it where the problem

Comment: You have to get scrollheight of the object first then you have to scroll till that as give below:
$('#infodiv').animate({ scrollTop: $(buildFailureObject.scrollHeight - 20 }, 2000);

Comment: @giorgio yes I have and that data is correct.

Comment: @brijrajsinh so is there no .position() anymore?

Comment: sorry, it will be like this: $('#infodiv').animate({ scrollTop: $(buildFailureObject).scrollHeight - 20 }, 2000);

Comment: There is, but position is relative to it's parent, while scrollTop is relative to the window. You should use `offset()` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured out the answer, I needed this:

$('#infodiv').animate({scrollTop:($('#infodiv').scrollTop() + $(buildFailureObject).position().top -20)}, 2000);